# How to log which executed SQL statement is deleting records from SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server table where rows randomly get deleted. I want to check what is causing this as I see no issues from the application side.

I did create an `after delete` trigger and I am able to see which rows are being deleted, but that is still not helping pin-point on why some records are being deleted.

I am wondering if it is possible to log/track which executed SQL statement are deleting the rows from my table.

Please note I am using SQL Server 2016 Express edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the help of SQL Profiler ..

Inside the profiler you can choose the events against your server..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that is exactly what i was looking for, do you know if you can target a specific database or table

Comment: you can specify the database..please see the updated  answer..

Comment: Thanks so much, what about a particular table in that database, or is that asking too much lol

Comment: i think in the objectName you can specify your table.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use triggers to trace queries

You can use Extended events to track DML against a particular table.They are light weight in nature and you also can use them to log to disk for later analysis..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it appears Auditing is not available for Express edition

Comment: @user1704812:This is not auditing,these are extended events,i don't they have edition restrictions..https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yep easiest way might be to create a trigger then use extended events to fire when the objectid of the trigger shows that it has been executed. And capture the TSQL call stack  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149717/73226